# How to use 'this.pros.function' to call the function running in the component context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to write a npm package `somePackage`. Now I write another codes to use this package. If the custom code write the `functionA`, I would use itself `functionA`, otherwise I will use the `functionA` in this package. But I failed to make the custom `functionA` running in the `somePackage` context.

```
class somePackage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    functionA () {
        if (this.props.functionA)
            this.props.functionA.call(this);
        ...some other codes...
    }
}

class customComponent extends React.Component{
    ...
    functionA(){
        this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...this.state.tags, tag] }));
    }

    render(){
        return (<somePackage/>)
    }
}
```

I hope the `this.props.functionA.call(this)` could make the `this.props.functionA` running in the `somePackage` context, but it actually is running in the `customComponent` context. This `this` pointer is still pointing to the customComponent.

Comment: Use arrow function instead of normal functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the arrow function syntax instead:

```
    functionA = () => { // arrow function allows "this" to refer to the class when the function is called
        if (this.props.functionA)
            this.props.functionA.call(this);
        ...some other codes...
    }
```